# `static constexpr auto` data-member initialized with unnamed enum

Tags: c++, c++11, enums, language-lawyer, auto

I was working on a C++11 project solely using `clang++-3.4`, and decided to compile using `g++-4.8.2` in case there were any discrepancies in the errors produced. It turned out that g++ rejects some code that clang++ accepts. I have reduced the problem to the MWE given below.

---

```
enum { a };

template <class T>
struct foo
{
    static constexpr auto value = a;
};

int main()
{
    static constexpr auto r = foo<int>::value;
}
```

> foo.cpp:5:23: error: ‘`const<anonymous enum> foo<int>::value`’, declared using anonymous type, is used but never defined [-fpermissive]
>
> ```
> static const auto value = A;
> ```

---

I would like some help answering the following two questions:

- Which compiler is correct in its interpretation of the standard? I am assuming that one compiler is right in either accepting or rejecting the code, and the other is wrong.
- How can I work around this issue? I can't name the anonymous enum, because it is from a third-party library (in my case, the enums were `Eigen::RowMajor` and `Eigen::ColMajor`).

Comment: Did you define the variable? Or what is the error message?

Comment: @Arcoth I don't think he has provided a definition, the error goes away if you do. [Here's](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92765cc8cb900ddf) the error message. I *think* the question is whether referring to `foo<T>::value` constitutes odr-use. gcc seems to think yes, while clang thinks no.

Comment: @Praetorian Yes, sorry, I stupidly forgot to include the actual error message.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Who's to blame?

*GCC*  is inaccurately rejecting your snippet, it is legal according to the *C++11* Standard (N3337). Quotations with proof and explanation is located the end of this post.

**workaround (A)** - *add the missing definition*

```
template <class T>
struct foo {
    static constexpr auto value = a;
    typedef decltype(a) value_type;
};

template<class T>
constexpr typename foo<T>::value_type foo<T>::value;
```

**workaround (B)** - *use the underlying-type of the enumeration as placeholder*

```
#include <type_traits>

template <class T>
struct foo {
  static const std::underlying_type<decltype(a)>::type value = a;
};
```

---

### What does the Standard say?  ([N3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3337.pdf))

As stated, the snippet is legal *C++11*, as can be read in the following quoted sections.

---

**When can we use a type without linkage?**

`[basic.link]p8` has detailed wording that describes when a type is *"without linkage"*, and it states that an unnamed enumeration count as such type.

`[basic.link]p8` also explicitly states three contexts where such a type cannot be used, but not one of the contexts apply to our usage, so we are safe.

> > A type without linkage shall not be used as the type of a variable or function with external linkage unless
> >
> > - the entity has C language linkage (7.5), or
> > - the entity is declared within an unnamed namespace (7.3.1), or
> > - the entity is not [odr-used](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Definition_Rule) (3.2) or is defined in the same translation unit

#### Are you sure we can use `auto` in such context?

Yes, and this can be proven by the following quote:

> `7.1.6.4p` **`auto` specifier** `[dcl.spec.auto]`
>
> > A `auto` *type-specifier* can also be used in declaring a variable in the condition of a selection statement (6.4) or an iteration statement (6.5), in the *type-specifier-seq* in the *new-type-id* or *type-id* of a *new-expression* (5.3.4), in a *for-range-declaration*, and in declaring a static data member with a *brace-or-equal-initializer* that appears within the *member-specification* of a class definition (9.4.2).

Comment: **Note**: `template<class T> struct foo { static constexpr auto value = a; } template<class T> constexpr decltype (foo<T>::value) foo<T>::value;` should work as a *workaround*, but latest clang rejects it. currently investigating if it's a bug or not.

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer and workarounds. Did you file a report for the original bug in GCC yet? If you like, you can go ahead and do it. Otherwise, I can do the honors.

Comment: @void-pointer Honestly I was just about to do it, do you wanna write one up? If so; it's all yours.

Comment: You can do it if you prefer; it's totally up to you. I was just offering in case you would rather someone else do it.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp I am not sure if `[basic.link]p8` is really relevant here. It says "_A type without linkage shall not be used as the type of a **variable** or function_...", where in the standard is it mentioned that enumerator name is a variable?

Answer (score 10):

> Which compiler is correct in its interpretation of the standard?

`gcc` is incorrect. §9.4.2/3:

> A static data member of literal type can be declared in the class
>   definition with the constexpr specifier; if so, its declaration shall
>   specify a brace-or-equal-initializer in which every initializer-clause
>   that is an assignment-expression is a constant expression. **The member
>   shall still be defined in a namespace scope *if it is odr-used*** (3.2) in
>   the program and the namespace scope definition shall not contain an
>   initializer.

And the name is not odr-used as per §3.2:

> A variable whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression is
>   *odr-used* **unless it is an object that satisfies the requirements for appearing in a constant expression (5.19) and the lvalue-to-rvalue
>   conversion (4.1) is immediately applied**.

This is indeed the case: It does satisfy the requirements for appearing in a constant expression and the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is immediately applied (it is used as an initializer for an object). So GCC's rejection is incorrect.

---

A possible workaround is to define the member (but without a placeholder type). This definition is sufficient for both Clang and GCC:

```
template< typename T >
constexpr decltype(a) foo<T>::value;
```

Answer (score 5):

Workaround with `decltype`:

```
enum { a };

template <class T>
struct foo
{
    static constexpr auto value = a;
};

template <class T>
constexpr decltype(a) foo<T>::value;

int main()
{
    static constexpr auto r = foo<int>::value;
}
```